# How would I test an alarm that is meant to fire every 30 days?

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

This is more of a testing question, but is there a way to change the phones date in the emulator or genymotion to see if an alarm in my app would actually fire on the 30 day mark?

Edit: This may not be clear but its not an actual alarm from the clock app. Its an alarm made with the alarmmanager that triggers a notification that I want to test.

Comment: Is this a programming question, mate? If not, other users will downvote your question as SO is reserved for programming-related questions. You might want to ask your question in another StackExchange forum.

Comment: If testing your code is a programing question than yes. Effective testing makes a good programmer. If you don't test anything you shouldn't be programming.

Comment: Your edit regarding `AlarmManager` will make it easier to identify this question as a programming-related question. I have upvoted your post as someone has downvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the time and date of your emulator, just like you can change the time and date on a device. I can confirm, from personal experience, that this will trigger your scheduled alarms correctly.